# ¿Cuál es el equivalente al registro de Windows en Android?

Tags: android, encriptación, registro-windows, storage

Tenía un conjunto de aplicaciones escritas para Windows Mobile, y las tengo que pasar a Android (Xamarin.Forms). Cuando las tenía en Windows, usaba el registro de Windows para guardar ciertos datos (llaves de encriptación). Necesito saber dónde guardar estos datos.

1. Android no tiene un registro como tal.
2. SQLite, no es una buena opción ya que una de las llaves de encriptación es para una base de datos, así que tendría que ser capaz de verla.
3. Memoria (Interna o externa), no parece demasiado seguro.
4. Preferencias de usuario, no me suena a muy seguro.
5. Hard coded: mala práctica.
6. Resources or app config. Intento separar el código de la llave... por temas de seguridad, así que tampoco.
7. Donde se guardan habitualmente contraseñas de aplicaciones, pero ni idea de dónde es esto.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Para más información, estoy trabajando en una dll que usa la aplicación que es donde necesito la llave de encriptación. Esta dll se usará en otras aplicaciones escritas bajo el mismo contexto (escritas actualmente para Windows mobile, reescritas para Android). El principal problema que me estoy encontrando es que todas las soluciones que encuentro son para la aplicación, pero en este caso se trata de una dll, con lo que la llave tiene que ser privada pero accesible por la librería, y por lo tanto por todas las aplicaciones que la usen que son bastantes (el número exacto no lo sé pero calculo que unas 20)

El diccionario de propiedades, sospecho, que es solo para la aplicación pero en este caso no se me ajusta, ya que es una librería que intento independizar de la aplicación, aunque actualmente sea escrito para Android.

Uso .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: En Android podrías usar `SharedPreferences` pero combinándolo con otras prácticas como `MODE_PRIVATE` o encriptación. [Aquí hay una buena guía](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/storing-data-securely-on-android--cms-30558) donde se exponen varios contextos de uso y recomendaciones útiles para cada caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar que Android tiene algo que se llama KeyStore (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). Así que voy a usar esto, que parece apropiado para mi caso.

Problema anterior: solo vale para una app, si haces varias apps no pueden acceder, todas necesitan su llave, el problema, que es la misma, así que haciendo un poco más de búsqueda he encontrado KeyChain (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808184/keystore-vs-keychain), que parece que va más para el caso, problema, es para Android, como es para una librería que usa la App, tendría que pasar el parámetro

Answer (score 3):

Una opción recomendable es utilizar el **diccionario de propiedades** `Application.Current.Properties[]`.

El diccionario `Properties` te permite un almacenamiento del tipo **clave/valor** que se guarda automáticamente en el dispositivo. Los datos agregados al diccionario están disponibles cuando la aplicación vuelve desde el segundo plano o incluso después de su reinicio.

```
Application.Current.Properties ["id"] = someClass.ID;
```

---

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
    var id = Application.Current.Properties ["id"] as int;
    // do something with id
}
```

**Referencia**: [Diccionario de propiedades](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary)

---

**UPDATE**: Xamarin.Forms 1.4 ha incorporado un método adicional a la clase Application `SavePropertiesAsync()` al que se puede llamar para conservar de forma proactiva el diccionario Properties. Esto permite guardar propiedades después de actualizaciones importantes en lugar de arriesgarse a que no se serialicen debido a un bloqueo o a su eliminación por parte del sistema operativo.